# Maximum call stack size exceeded error in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

In response to Ajax call, I am receiving a list of objects. When I try to pass it to another function to display that list in table, it shows "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error. I am calling that function only once i.e. not in loop, but it shows first alert 'welcome' repeatedly from function. It does not hit any of remaining alerts in the function. How can I fix it?

** ajax code:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Read_Quran?ayah="+ayah,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: '',
    success: function (result) 
    {
        alert("back to succes.!");
        var mera_obj = result.key;  
        show_table(mera_obj,0,10);
        return false;
    }, 
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
   {
        alert("Error :   " + xhr.responseText);
   },
});
```

**function :**

```
function show_table(mera_obj,start,end)
{
   alert("welcome " +start +" " +end);

   var nrCols=3;
   var maxRows=10;
   var nrRows=maxRows+1;
   var root=document.getElementById('mydiv');
   var tab=document.createElement('table');
   tab.style.width='800';

   tab.style.backgroundColor = 'white'  ;      
   tab.setAttribute('Border','1');
   tab.className="mytable";
   var tbo=document.createElement('tbody');
   var tr1= document.createElement('tr');
   var th1= document.createElement('th');
   th1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Ayat_#'));
   th1.style.width='60';
   var th2= document.createElement('th');
   th2.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Verse'));

   var th3= document.createElement('th');
   th3.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Translation'));
   alert("Second setp");
   tr1.appendChild(th1);
   tr1.appendChild(th2);
   tr1.appendChild(th3);
   tbo.appendChild(tr1);
   alert("before showing");
   for (index = 0; index < 1/*mera_obj.length*/; ++index) 
   {                        
       //jquery code for table
       var row, cell;
       row=document.createElement('tr');
       cell1=document.createElement('td');
       cell1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mera_obj[index].ayah)) //ayah no

       cell2=document.createElement('td');
       cell2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mera_obj[index].verse)) // contents
       cell2.style.width="350";     

       cell3=document.createElement('td');
       cell3.appendChild(document.createTextNode('not_available')) // translation
       row.appendChild(cell1);
       row.appendChild(cell2);
       row.appendChild(cell3);
       tbo.appendChild(row);
       // alert(mera_obj[index].surah_name+" >"+mera_obj[index].verse + mera_obj[index].surah);
   }
   tab.appendChild(tbo);
   var BB= document.createElement('input');
   BB.setAttribute('type','button');
   BB.setAttribute('value','<<Back');
   BB.style.position="relative";
   BB.style.left="2";

   var FB= document.createElement('input');
   FB.setAttribute('type','button');
   FB.setAttribute('value','Next>>');
   FB.style.position="relative";
   FB.style.left="20";

   var RT= document.createElement('input');
   RT.setAttribute('type','text');
   RT.setAttribute('value','10');
   RT.style.position="relative";
   RT.style.left="30";
   RT.style.width="45";
   RT.setAttribute('placeholder','Range');

   root.appendChild(tab);
   root.appendChild(BB);
   root.appendChild(FB);
   root.appendChild(RT);

   return false;
}
```

Comment: inside `show_table` you are calling `show_table` again creating an infinitely recursive loop,  that is the cause

Comment: thank you, actually there was mess of code ...

Comment: Is it still happening? If so, hiw are you calling `show_table`?